# Minors of a particular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory, arithmetic-combinatorics, total-unimodularity

Take an $\frac{n(n-1)}2\times n$ matrix $M$ with $0/1$ entries

1. each row distinct
2. each row having two $1$s.

Take an $\frac{n(n-1)}2\times \frac{n(n-1)}2$ matrix $N$ with $0/1$ entries

1. each row distinct
2. each row having a single $1$
3. if $M$ has a row with columns $i,j$ marked as $1$ then $N$ has in the same row $(i-1)\times (n-i) + (j-i)$ column marked as $1$.

Then does only powers of $2$ occur as minors (absolute values of cofactors) of matrix $\begin{bmatrix}M&N\end{bmatrix}$ ?

$M=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&0&0\\
1&0&1&0\\
1&0&0&1\\
0&1&1&0\\
0&1&0&1\\
0&0&1&1
\end{bmatrix}$, $N=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}M&N\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&0&1&0&0&1&0&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&0&0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&1&0&1&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$ is matrix example at $n=4$.

I think minor structure of $M$ is same as minor structure of $\begin{bmatrix}M&N\end{bmatrix}$ and $N$ might be disregarded.

Comment: Ok, but did you test it, or is it just a thought experiment?

Comment: It would be helpful to show an actual example.

Comment: The newly included example definitely improves the question.

Comment: When you say "minor" what exactly do you mean? ?? $n\times n$ minor??

Comment: You say "a[n] .. matrix $M$ " and "matrix example for $n=4$". Surely there's a unique $M$ up to ordering the columns and rows sensibly?

Comment: I see minors of value $0$.

Comment: But some are not powers of $2$.

Comment: The $1\times 1$ and $2\times 2$ ones which are patently $0$.

Comment: If you're to allow $2^{-\infty}$ you should say so.

Answer (score 2):

*As no one has attempted a solution let me at least identify what a minimal counterexample would look like. If any minor fails then one of the form $Z+Z^{-1}$ fails, where $Z$ is the permutation matrix of the cycle $(1 2 \dots n)$.*

**Setup** Perhaps it helps to view $M$ as the vertex-edge incidence matrix of the $n$-simplex. That is the columns are indexed by the elements of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and the rows by the elements of the $2$-sets $\{1,2,\dots,n\}^{(2)}$; with $m_{\{a,b\},c}=1$ if $c\in\{a,b\}$ and $0$ otherwise.

With a suitable re-ordering if the columns of $n$ we have $N=I$.

**Preliminary** Let us see that the minors of $(M\ I)$ are found among the minors of $M$. Consider some minor $K$. If the corresponding column choice chooses only columns of $M$ the result is trivial, so suppose that $s$ columns of $I$ are involved. By suitably renaming everything we can suppose that the first $s$ columns of $I$ are chosen. Now if the first $s$ rows of $(M\ I)$ are not all chosen we have in $K$ a column of $0$s and are done. Otherwise $K$ is of the form $\det\begin{pmatrix} A & I\\B & O\end{pmatrix}=\det B$ and we are done.

**Minimal Counterexample $\mathbf{K}$** We consider only $M$ and what we intend to prove is that every $k\times k$ minor, for $k=1,\dots n$, is up to sign either $0$ or a natural power of $2$. We argue by induction, noting that all is clear for small values. If the result is false we consider the least $n$ for which there is a counterexample, and then with this $n$, the least $k$ for which there is a counterexample, the minor $K$ say.

**Rows and columns of  $\mathbf{K}$** If $K$ has any row (or column) of $0$s then its value is $0$ and so is no counterexample. If $K$ has any row (or column) with a single $1$ then we can expand $K$ along that row (or column) and get that $K$ is equal to a $(k-1)\times (k-1)$ minor and so is no counterexample. To summarise: each row and column of $K$ has exactly two $1$s.

**The meaning of $\mathbf{K}$** By the above we can view $K$ as the incidence matrix of a graph $\Gamma$ with $k$ vertices and $k$ edges: every vertex is on two edges and every edge joins two vertices.

**The structure of $\mathbf{\Gamma}$** Then $\Gamma$ must be a disjoint union of cycles. Suitable reordering the rows and columns of $K$ we see that if there is more than one cycle then the underlying matrix of $K$ must be of the form $\begin{pmatrix}A & O\\O & B\end{pmatrix}$, and then $K$ is the product of two minors of smaller dimension and so no counterexample. That is $\Gamma$ is a single cycle.

**$\mathbf{k=n}$** Clearly if $k<n$ then this same structure occurs in the $(n-1)$ simplex, and so by the minimality of $n$ this is not a counterexample.

**The structure of $\mathbf{K}$** We can suppose now without loss that the columns involved in $K$ are the first $k$. After a suitable permutation of the columns and labelling of the edges we can suppose that the cycle is $1-
2-3-\dots-k-1$. Let $Z$ denote the permutation matrix of $(123\dots k)$; it is the usual circulant matrix. Then our incidence matrix $K$ is just $Z+Z^{-1}$.

**The determinant of $\mathbf{Z+Z^{-1}}$** The eigenvalues of $Z$ are of course $\{\zeta^j| j=0,\dots, k-1\}$ where $\zeta$ is the primitive $k$-th root of unity $e^{2\pi/k}$. $Z$ and $Z^{-1}$ simultaneously diagonalise. Hence the determinant of $K$ is $\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(\zeta^{j}+\zeta^{-j})=2^{k}\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\cos\frac{2\pi}{k}$.

**The value of $\mathbf{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\cos\frac{2\pi}{k}}$** This has something to do with Chebychev polynomials, but I cannot at the moment sort it out.